# how to get part of request URI into path variable in spring mvc rest services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, url-mapping

my service code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/resources/web/{path}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getWebFileContent(@PathVariable("projectId") String projectId,@PathVariable("path") String path, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
}
```

And my request will be

- /projects/pro1/resources/web/src/main/webapp
- /projects/pro1/resources/web/src/main/test/com/pro1...

and is it possible to get "src/main/webapp/../....." into "path" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provide three patterns in the url handler mappings

- ? - zero or one charecter
- *- one charecter
- ** - one or more charecters

And below approach resolved my issue

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/resources/web/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getWebFileContent(@PathVariable("projectId") String projectIdHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
    String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE); 
    // will get path = /projects/pro1/resources/web/src/main/webapp
    String bestMatchPattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    // will get bestMatchPattern = /projects/pro1/resources/web/**
    AntPathMatcher apm = new AntPathMatcher();
    String exactPath = apm.extractPathWithinPattern(bestMatchPattern, path);
    // will get exactPath = src/main/webapp
    .....
}
```

Any other approaches are appreciated....